# Calculate the variance of list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Suppose that we have this:

```
d_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1, 3, 4], 'y' : [3, 2, 1]})
d_2 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [5, 6, 7], 'y' : [10, 11, 12]})
d_3 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [16, 17, 18], 'y' : [19, 11, 12]})

out = [d_1, d_2, d_3]
```

I want to calculate the standard deviation (element-by-element) of list of data-frames (`out`). As a result, the first value should be standard deviation 1, 5, and 16. How can I do that in python?

Answer (score -2):

I changed my answer, since you edited your question:

Here is a bit of code to print the standard deviation (given that your dataframes have the same index and columns):

```py
import numpy as np

for idx in out[0].index:
    for col in out[0]:
        values = [df.loc[idx, col] for df in out]
        print(col, idx, np.std(values), values)
```

Output:

```py
x 0 6.342099196813483 [1, 5, 16]
y 0 6.548960901462833 [3, 10, 19]
x 1 6.018490028422596 [3, 6, 17]
y 1 4.242640687119285 [2, 11, 11]
x 2 6.018490028422596 [4, 7, 18]
y 2 5.185449728701348 [1, 12, 12]
```